# How to start using Material2 using ES5 and old fashion of including scripts and styles in head section of HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material2

I'm able to use Angular2 using old fashioned script inclusion in head section of my HTML page and dosing some bootstrapping and things are just fine. However now that I want to add Material 2, I can't find a simple guide for inclusion of this module into my app module dependencies, and include the css very simply somewhere in the head section.

This is a sample of what I include in my page:

```
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/coreJsShimMin.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/zoneMin.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/rxMin.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/angularCoreUmd.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/angularCommonUmd.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/angularCompilerUmd.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/angularPlatformBrowserUmd.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/angularPlatformBrowserDynamicUmd.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/angularFormsUmd.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/thirdParties/angularHttpUmd.js"></script>
```

Is there a simple old-fahsioned guide for using Material 2? After all, it's a simple JavaScript/Css combination that needs to be included on the page